# Impossible to add a User-Defined-Data Type parameter to my query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-types

I'm trying to use a User-Defined-Data Type with C# and SQL Server 2008 but I have an exception raised when command.ExecuteReader() is executed.

```
string qyery = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE IsAvailableProduct < @Param";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qyery, conn);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Param", SqlDbType.Structured);

param.UdtTypeName = "MyBolean";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.Value = 1;

command.Parameters.Add(param);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The raised exception is :

> ``` Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a IEnumerable``1. ```

What's wrong in my code ?

**EDIT** :

If I change the **SqlDbType** to **Udt**, I have this exception : `Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.`

If I set the **DbType** property to **Int** (which is the base type of "MyBolean") the result is the exception `Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a IEnumerable`1.`` is raised too.

**EDIT** :

I modified the title because in SQL Server 2008, it's "User Define DATA Type" and no "User Defined Types"

Comment: I suggest you add a definition of your UDT to the question =)

Answer (score 2):

The [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) enumeration value `Structured` is used to indicate that you're passing around a [Table Value Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), which is why you're getting the error message you're getting as the value you're passing in is an integer, not a "list of something" for use as a TVP.

You need to set `param.SqlDbType` based on the underlying datatype for `MyBolean` which I suspect is probably `Bit` or `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would guess you at least need to make `SqlDbType = Udt` (not Stuctured).

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use UdtTypeName="MyBoolean"
   this type must exist in your
   database
2. also if you set
   SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured your
   type "MyBoolean" must be
   "table-valued parameter" [look at
   this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) and [more info about using table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

so when you set those properies parameter value must be at least implement IEnumerable (i.e. a list of objects), but you provide integer value and this caused error

Answer (score 0):

I have User-Defined Table Types in my database (assume this to be MyTableTypeList). These are used as parameters in my stored procedure.
To pass values through this data type I do the following:

Declare a DataTable similar to my User-Defined Table Type, populate values in it.

Assign SqlParameter property SqlDbType as SqlDbType.Structured "param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured"

Assign TypeName property with the name of the User-Defnied Table Type. "param.TypeName = "MyTableTypeList"

Answer (score 0):

`Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`: I'm afraid, you cannot use primitive types, like `int32` or `string` in the `Value` property of a `Udt` type parameter. You should either create your custom UDT-Classes in .NET (decorating them with the [SqlUserDefinedTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedtypeattribute)) and register them on the SQL-Server (see the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/creating-user-defined-types)), or you can "fallback" to use the base SQL-types your UDTs based on, like `Decimal`, `DateTime`, `NVarChar` etc. in your .NET code instead of `Udt`. I faced the very same problem, and voted for the second option.